# Abstracting Case Classes

Tags: scala, case-class, dependent-method-type, scala-2.10

I'm exploring ways to abstract Case Classes in Scala. For example, here is an attempt for `Either[Int, String]` (using Scala 2.10.0-M1 and `-Yvirtpatmat`):

```
trait ApplyAndUnApply[T, R] extends Function1[T, R] {
  def unapply(r: R): Option[T]
}

trait Module {
  type EitherIntOrString
  type Left <: EitherIntOrString
  type Right <: EitherIntOrString
  val Left: ApplyAndUnApply[Int, Left]
  val Right: ApplyAndUnApply[String, Right]
}
```

Given this definition, I could write something like that:

```
def foo[M <: Module](m: M)(intOrString: m.EitherIntOrString): Unit = {
  intOrString match {
    case m.Left(i) => println("it's an int: "+i)
    case m.Right(s) => println("it's a string: "+s)
  }
}
```

Here is a first implementation for the module, where the representation for the `Either` is a `String`:

```
object M1 extends Module {
  type EitherIntOrString = String
  type Left = String
  type Right = String
  object Left extends ApplyAndUnApply[Int, Left] {
    def apply(i: Int) = i.toString
    def unapply(l: Left) = try { Some(l.toInt) } catch { case e: NumberFormatException => None }
  }
  object Right extends ApplyAndUnApply[String, Right] {
    def apply(s: String) = s
    def unapply(r: Right) = try { r.toInt; None } catch { case e: NumberFormatException => Some(r) }
  }
}
```

The `unapply`s make the `Left` and `Right` really exclusive, so the following works as expecting:

```
scala> foo(M1)("42")
it's an int: 42

scala> foo(M1)("quarante-deux")
it's a string: quarante-deux
```

So far so good. My second attempt is to use `scala.Either[Int, String]` as the natural implementation for `Module.EitherIntOrString`:

```
object M2 extends Module {
  type EitherIntOrString = Either[Int, String]
  type Left = scala.Left[Int, String]
  type Right = scala.Right[Int, String]
  object Left extends ApplyAndUnApply[Int, Left] {
    def apply(i: Int) = scala.Left(i)
    def unapply(l: Left) = scala.Left.unapply(l)
  }
  object Right extends ApplyAndUnApply[String, Right] {
    def apply(s: String) = scala.Right(s)
    def unapply(r: Right) = scala.Right.unapply(r)
  }
}
```

But this does not work as expected:

```
scala> foo(M2)(Left(42))
it's an int: 42

scala> foo(M2)(Right("quarante-deux"))
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Right cannot be cast to scala.Left
```

Is there a way to get the right result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this matcher:

```
intOrString match {
    case m.Left(i) => println("it's an int: "+i)
    case m.Right(s) => println("it's a string: "+s)
}
```

It unconditionally executes `m.Left.unapply` on the `intOrString`. As to why it does, see below.

When you call `foo(M2)(Right("quarante-deux"))` this is what is happening:

- `m.Left.unapply` resolves to `M2.Left.unapply` which is in fact `scala.Left.unapply`
- `intOrString` is `Right("quarante-deux")`

Consequently, `scala.Left.unapply` is called on `Right("quarante-deux")` which causes CCE.

Now, why this happens. When I tried to run your code through the interpreter, I got these warnings:

```
<console>:21: warning: abstract type m.Left in type pattern m.Left is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
           case m.Left(i) => println("it's an int: "+i)
                  ^
<console>:22: warning: abstract type m.Right in type pattern m.Right is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
           case m.Right(s) => println("it's a string: "+s)
                   ^
```

The `unapply` method of `ApplyAndUnApply` gets erased to `Option unapply(Object)`. Since it's impossible to run something like `intOrString instanceof m.Left` (because `m.Left` is erased too), the compiler compiles this match to run all erased `unapply`s.

One way to get the right result is below(not sure if it goes along with your original idea of abstracting case classes):

```
trait Module {
    type EitherIntOrString
    type Left <: EitherIntOrString
    type Right <: EitherIntOrString
    val L: ApplyAndUnApply[Int, EitherIntOrString]
    val R: ApplyAndUnApply[String, EitherIntOrString]
}

object M2 extends Module {
    type EitherIntOrString = Either[Int, String]
    type Left = scala.Left[Int, String]
    type Right = scala.Right[Int, String]
    object L extends ApplyAndUnApply[Int, EitherIntOrString] {
        def apply(i: Int) = Left(i)
        def unapply(l: EitherIntOrString) = if (l.isLeft) Left.unapply(l.asInstanceOf[Left]) else None
    }
    object R extends ApplyAndUnApply[String, EitherIntOrString] {
        def apply(s: String) = Right(s)
        def unapply(r: EitherIntOrString) = if (r.isRight) Right.unapply(r.asInstanceOf[Right]) else None
    }
}
```

Comment: Great explanation! I've decided to solve my issue... by not using pattern matching :-) Defining a fold function is easier and more robust.